# add +n to the name of some Strings id ends with "v + number"

Tags: java, regex

I have an array of Strings

```
Value[0] = "Documento v1.docx";
Value[1] = "Some_things.pdf";
Value[2] = "Cosasv12.doc";
Value[3] = "Document16.docx";
Value[4] = "Nodoc";
```

I want to change the name of the document and add +1 to the version of every document. But only the Strings of documents that ends with v{number} (v1, v12, etc).

I used the regex `[v]+a*^` but only i obtain the "v" and not the number after the "v"

Comment: Please explain why you expect that regex to work. What is ``a*`` going to do?

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve]. Use the "edit" link to improve your *question* - do not add more information via comments. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all your strings ending with `v` + digits + extension are to be processed, use a pattern like `v(\\d+)(?=\\.[^.]+$)` and then manipulate the value of Group 1 inside the `Matcher#appendReplacement` method:

```
String[] strs = { "Documento v1.docx", "Some_things.pdf", "Cosasv12.doc", "Document16.docx", "Nodoc"};
Pattern pat = Pattern.compile("v(\\d+)(?=\\.[^.]+$)");
for (String s: strs) {
    StringBuffer result = new StringBuffer();
    Matcher m = pat.matcher(s);
    while (m.find()) {
            int n = 1 + Integer.parseInt(m.group(1));
        m.appendReplacement(result, "v" + n);
    }
    m.appendTail(result);
    System.out.println(result.toString());
}
```

See the [Java demo](https://ideone.com/fKwa8u)

Output:

```
Documento v2.docx
Some_things.pdf
Cosasv13.doc
Document16.docx
Nodoc
```

**Pattern details**

- `v` - a `v`
- `(\d+)` - Group 1 value: one or more digits
- `(?=\.[^.]+$)` - that are followed with a literal `.` and then 1+ chars other than `.` up to the end of the string.

Answer (score 1):

The Regex `v\d+` should match on the letter `v`, followed by a number (please note that you may need to write it as `v\\d+` when assigning it to a String). Further enhancement of the Regex depends in what your code looks like. You may want to to wrap in a Capturing Group like `(v\d+)`, or even `(v(\d+))`.

The first reference a quick search turns up is
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/ ,
which should be a good starting point.

Answer (score 0):

Try a regex like this:

```
([v])([1-9]{1,3})(\.)
```

notice that I've already included the point in order to have less "collisions" and a maximum of 999 versions({1,3}).

Further more I've used 3 different groups so that you can easily retrieve the version number increase it and replace the string.

Example:

```
String regex = ;
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(time);
if(matcher.matches()){
  int version = matcher.group(2); // don't remember if is 0 or 1 based
}
```